# SharePoint Lists Connection to Tableau

Tags: sharepoint, tableau-api

I am looking to take the data off a sharepoint 2013 website and connect it to Tableau. I have established a direct connection but since sharepoint is not a relational db the data is being read incorrectly. I am thinking what are other possible solutions?

Is it possible to store the data from sharepoint into a SQL database then connect Tableau to SQL directly?

All tips & advice will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: You can do it using the either OData or Sharepoint List Here is the process for using OData-
https://community.tableau.com/docs/DOC-6184 Here is the way to use sharepoint list-
https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-gb/examples_sharepoint_lists.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the OData connector in Tableau to read data from a SharePoint site if you must (I'm not a huge fan of storing enterprise data in a SharePoint list, especially anything more complicated than a phone list).

The biggest pain to avoid is that SharePoint allows (even encourages) people to store repeated lists of values in a cell. Using that "feature" in SharePoint complicates analysis by any approach or tool designed for relational data such as Tableau. You can still use Tableau in that case, but the field with multiple values per cell will be a hassle to use with filters and calculations.

So my tips are:

- strongly encourage your SharePoint friends to not stuff multiple values in a single field
- use the OData connector (or the commercial SharePoint connector if needed)
- if the data is complex, try to encourage them to use a proper database to store the data instead of a SharePoint list (they can still use SharePoint for forms and display if they know what they're doing)